# Environment variable are not hidden (secure)?

Tags: angular, typescript, security, environment

I found with my browser inspector some private credentials located in my environment file. They're not hidden ? That's not secure...
I did something wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you included them in your environment.ts in your Angular project then they will not be hidden. You can not include any secret values directly in your front-end Angular project as everything will be transferred to the client.

If you need to use a secret of some kind then usually they are only accessible by your back-end code and hidden behind your API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm using Google MAP Javascript API, how i'm supposed to do to secure my API key ? There is no solution ?

Comment: I am not that familiar with the Google Maps API, but it might be that the API key is something you can publicly share. You probably find somerhing about it in the documentation, or if not, you can do another Stackoverflow question specifically about that.

Comment: Ok, that's was just an exemple, I could be the salt of an password encryption when the user is login/registering